# Should there be a comma if "though" is used mid-sentence?

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

> In an effort to showcase my enthusiasm, all of my personal projects since graduation
> relate to health in some form though I do have a distinct interest in the study of
> behavior and the mind.

It's used mid-sentence. Should I include a comma?

Comment: Yes, but. The word *though* subtracts from your opening statement. I'd separate and restart with *I also have*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin. I have a lot of sentences starting with 'I' in this letter. Is there any way of joining the two without creating another sentence?

Comment: ...relate to health in some form. Also, my distinct interest in the study of behavior and the mind led me to blah, blah, blah.

Comment: A comma isn't essential by any rule of grammar, but I agree you should consider breaking it up somehow. It's not too hard to comprehend, but it helps the reader if you indicate natural/logical breaks. There are a lot of similar questions about comma use (in some of which the debate is quite heated), and it's not specific to "though".